# How to give new users two user role options upon WordPress user registration

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, registration, user-roles

I have a website that has customers and vendors. What is the proper way to let the new registered user choose which role they want? Do they want to be as a customers and buy things or do they want to start selling.

I’m dreaming of a registration page where you could actually put your username, email and then from a dropdown button choose their role. Don’t know is this possible to do. Please see the attached picture.

Image of registration form:
[image: Image of registration form]

Comment: Your question is more appropriate for a different site, like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a plugin like Paid Membership Pro and make the different roles all free. I have used this for a similar project in the past and it all worked out. Check out the plugin site here https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/

Comment: I'd like to be able to do this without a plugin. Simply code in function.php.